# Miniconda installed but conda command not found

Tags: python, shell, miniconda

I'm completely new to programming so your patience is much appreciated!

I'm trying to install Miniconda 3 on my MacBook Air (M1 Chip). The installation seems successful every time but when I check with `conda list` it says command not found. I did add `export PATH="/Users/{username}/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"` as an environmental variable in `.profile`. I searched through previous boards and tried also adding the same environment variable to `.zhsrc`. When I add this, I now get the message that zsh killed the conda command. I've also tried using bash and I get the message killed:9. `conda --version` results in the same message. I've also tried deleting miniconda and re-installing it. And I am using the conda version for the M1 chip.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you verify that your PATH is setup correct? What does `echo $PATH` tell you?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.